# Bash - add new line including variables

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, vim, echo

I want to add this new line to my .bashrc:

```
Path=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

I used:

```
echo "PATH=\"$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin\"" >> ".bashrc"
```

But it inserted:

```
PATH="/home/ubuntu/bin:/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin:/bin:/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_102/bin:/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_102/bin:/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_102/bin"
```

Anybody could help with this issue?

I know i could use a text editor like vim, but as is a part of a script i need to use the

```
echo "string" >> file
```

variant

Thanks and Greetings!

Comment: You need to escape the `$` in `$PATH` so `$PATH` doesn't get expanded.  As it is, it's not really an error.  But it's more normal to leave `$PATH` unexpanded in a case like this where you're just appending another path.

Comment: Your inserted PATH ends with `/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_102/bin:/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_102/bin:/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_102/bin`. I think you ran your script 3 times! You should check the PATH before adding another folder.

Comment: What will happen when you install a new jdk version? When you append the new version to the PATH, executables in jdk1.8.0_102 will be found first. Can you add the path in a global resource or are you going to check this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape `$` for both `$PATH` and `$JAVA_HOME`

So it should be:

```
echo "PATH=\$PATH:\$JAVA_HOME/bin" >> ".bashrc"
```

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't you be escaping the dollar signs instead of adding quote marks and escaping those? 
And your command should have an export in front of it so it would end up being `echo "export PATH=\$PATH:\$JAVA_HOME/bin" >> .bashrc`

Answer (score 2):

To keep it prettier than the other answers here, you can use single quotes because variables will not be expanded:

```
echo 'PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin' >> .bashrc
```

Additionally, you're gonna want to remove all of the sections in .bashrc from your previous attempts, as until you do that your PATH will get pretty cluttered with duplicate and incorrect entries as seen in your example.